# Unbind click event does what I want but fires an javascript console error

Tags: jquery

If one Jquery plugin this code is executed:

```
dropdown = {
    doc: $(document),
    element: $('#user_info'),
    open: function() {
        if ( ! dropdown.element.hasClass('active') ) {
            dropdown.element.addClass('active');
            dropdown.doc.one( 'click', dropdown.close );
            return false;
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        dropdown.element.removeClass('active');
    }
};

dropdown.element.click( dropdown.open );
```

How can I disable/remove/unbind the click handler in my own custom (another file) Jquery plugin?

I was using this code:

```
dropdown = {
    doc: jQuery(document),
    element: jQuery('#user_info')
};

dropdown.element.click(function(e) {
    dropdown.element.unbind('click', dropdown.open);
});
```

I get what I want, but javascript console shows this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'unbind'...
```

Please let me know if there is a way to avoid this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it:

```
dropdown = {
    doc: jQuery(document),
    element: jQuery('#user_info'),
    open: function() {
        dropdown.element.addClass('active');
        dropdown.doc.one( 'click', dropdown.close );
        return true;
    },
    close: function() {
        dropdown.element.removeClass('active');
    }
};

dropdown.element.click( dropdown.open );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know if there is a way to avoid this error.

From you example it looks like you're missing a property name in your call to `unbind`. Don't you mean this?

```
dropdown = {
    doc: jQuery(document),
    element: jQuery('#user_info')
};

dropdown.element.click(function(e) {
    dropdown.element.unbind('click', dropdown.open);
});
```

Notice `dropdown.element.unbind()`. The variable `dropdown` isn't a jQuery object from your example, but `dropwdown.element` is.

Comment: Thanks Zack, I try it, but it doesnt work. But it works like a charm with the answer that I just post a few minutes ago.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't do what you want or it still generates an error?